# Aggregate dynamic columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a narrow table containing unique key and source data

| Unique_Key | System |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IT |
| 1 | ACCOUNTS |
| 1 | PAYROLL |
| 2 | IT |
| 2 | PAYROLL |
| 3 | IT |
| 4 | HR |
| 5 | PAYROLL |

I want to be able to pick a system as a base - in this case IT - then create a dynamic SQL query where it counts:

- distinct unique key in the chosen system
- proportion of shared unique key with other systems. These systems could be dynamic and there are lot more than 4

I'm thinking of using dynamic SQL and PIVOT to first pick out all the system names outside of IT. Then using IT as a base, join to that table to get the information.

```
select distinct Unique_Key, System_Name
into #staging
from dbo.data
where System_Name <> 'IT'

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(System_Name) 
            FROM #staging
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Unique_Key, ' + @cols + ' into dbo.temp from 
            (
                select Unique_Key, System_Name
                from #staging
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 count(System_Name)
                for System_Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

  select *
  from 
  (
    select distinct Unique_Key
  from dbo.data
  where System_Name = 'IT'
  ) a
  left join dbo.temp b
  on a.Unique_Key = b.Unique_Key
```

So the resulting table is:

| Unique_Key | PAYROLL | ACCOUNTS | HR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

What I want is one step further:

| Distinct Count IT Key | PAYROLL | ACCOUNTS | HR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 67% | 33% | 0% |

I can do a simple join with specific case when/sum statement but wondering if there's a way to do it dynamically so I don't need to specify every system name.

Appreciate any tips/hints.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing Dynamic Query, you start off with a non-dynamic query. Make sure you gets the result of the query is correct before you convert to dynamic query.

For the result that you required, the query will be

```
with cte as
(
    select it.Unique_Key, ot.System_Name
    from   data it
           left join data ot on it.Unique_Key = ot.Unique_Key
                            and ot.System_Name <> 'IT'
    where  it.System_Name = 'IT'
)
select  [ITKey]    = count(distinct Unique_Key), 
        [ACCOUNTS] = count(case when System_Name = 'ACCOUNTS' then Unique_Key end) * 100.0 
                   / count(distinct Unique_Key),
        [HR]       = count(case when System_Name = 'HR'       then Unique_Key end) * 100.0 
                   / count(distinct Unique_Key),
        [PAYROLL]  = count(case when System_Name = 'PAYROLL'  then Unique_Key end) * 100.0 
                   / count(distinct Unique_Key)
from   cte;
```

Once you get the result correct, it is not that difficult to convert to dynamic query. Use string_agg() or for xml path for those repeated rows

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

; with cte as
(
    select distinct System_Name
    from   data
    where  System_Name <> 'IT'
)
select  @sql = string_agg(sql1 + ' / ' + sql2, ',' + char(13))
from    cte
        cross apply
        (
            select sql1 = char(9) + quotename(System_Name) + ' = '
                        + 'count(case when System_Name = ''' + System_Name + ''' then Unique_Key end) * 100.0 ',
                   sql2 = 'count(distinct Unique_Key)'
        ) a

select  @sql = 'with cte as' + char(13)
             + '(' + char(13)
             + '    select it.Unique_Key, ot.System_Name' + char(13)
             + '    from   data it' + char(13)
             + '           left join data ot on it.Unique_Key = ot.Unique_Key' + char(13)
             + '                            and ot.System_Name <> ''IT''' + char(13)
             + '    where  it.System_Name = ''IT''' + char(13)
             + ')' + char(13)
             + 'select [ITKey] = count(distinct Unique_Key), ' + char(13)
             + @sql + char(13)
             + 'from   cte;' + char(13)

print @sql;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43792a67ddb52283b86288800112d726)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used string_agg before but it makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use dynamic SQL as below, I would use condition aggregate function get pivot value then we might add `OUTER JOIN` or EXISTS condition in dynamic SQL.

I would use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of `exec` to avoid sql-injection.

```
DECLARE @System_Name NVARCHAR(50) = 'IT' 
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @parameter AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
SET @parameter = '@System_Name NVARCHAR(50)'

select DISTINCT System_Name
into #staging
from dbo.data t1
WHERE t1.System_Name <> @System_Name



SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', SUM(IIF(System_Name = '''+ System_Name+''',1,0))  * 100.0 / SUM(IIF(System_Name = @System_Name,0,1)) ' + QUOTENAME(System_Name) 
            FROM #staging
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        
set @query = 'SELECT SUM(IIF(System_Name = @System_Name,0,1)) [Distinct Count IT Key], ' + @cols + ' from  dbo.data t1
 WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM dbo.data tt 
  WHERE tt.Unique_Key = t1.Unique_Key
  AND tt.System_Name = @System_Name
 ) '
 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, @parameter,  @System_Name
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82a6aaa56ac4aa7803a65754ecf6ee93)

Answer (score 1):

This solution changes the aggregation function of the PIVOT itself.

First, let's add a column [has_it] to #staging that keeps track of whether each Unique_Key has an IT row:

```
select Unique_Key, System_Name, case when exists(select 1 from data d2 where d2.Unique_Key=d1.Unique_Key and d2.System_Name='IT') then 1 else 0 end as has_it
into #staging
from data d1
where System_Name <> 'IT'
group by Unique_Key, System_Name
```

Now, the per-System aggregation (sum) of this column divided by the final total unique keys needed (example case=3) returns the requests numbers. Change the PIVOT to the following and it's ready as-is, without further queries:

```
set @query = '  select * 
    from 
        (
            select System_Name,cnt as [Distinct Count IT Key],has_it*1.0/cnt as divcnt
            from #staging
            cross join
            (   
                select count(distinct Unique_Key) as cnt
                from dbo.data
                where System_Name = ''IT''
            )y
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
                sum(divcnt)
            for System_Name in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p'
```